# Netty proxy - slow receiver handling

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I am new to netty and trying to work on a proxy that consumes from a publisher and sends to a slow receiver. I followed a presentation from Norman Maurer on how to reuse the `EventLoopGroup` for creating a proxy client. This is the code that bootstraps the proxy client.

```java
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();
        inboundChannel.config().setAutoRead(false);

        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap = AClient.configureBootstrap(hostName, port, bootstrap, inboundChannel.eventLoop());
        connectFuture = bootstrap.connect();

        connectFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                assert future == connectFuture;
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    inboundChannel.config().setAutoRead(true);
                }
            }
        });

        ChannelFuture closeFuture = connectFuture.channel().closeFuture();
        closeFuture.addListener(new AClientCloseFuture(this));
    }
```

The bootstrap for the proxy client:

```java
public static Bootstrap configureBootstrap(String hostName, int port, Bootstrap b, EventLoopGroup group) {
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.handler(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter());
        b.remoteAddress(hostName, port);
        b.group(group);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 5000 * 1024);
        b.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 3000 * 1024);

        return b;
    }
```

The following code shows how I have used it to manage writing to the slow receiver.

```java
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, AMessage aMessage) throws Exception {
            writeIfPossible(aMessage);
}

private void writeIfPossible(AMessage aMessage) {
        Channel channel = connectFuture.channel();
        // Block until the host can accept requests. It may be stalled because of slow receiving by the
        // host or if it is down. Is running a loop here wrong? Will it never come out of the loop once it gets in?
        while (true) {
            if (channel.isWritable()) {
            channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(aMessage.getMessage(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

In the above code I run a while (true) to force it to block until the channel is writable again. I do this because all these messages need to be delivered without fail. But I think by running a while (true) I am blocking the whole event loop group and hence the `channel.isWritable()` is always false as the thread is stuck running the while loop even though the channel becomes free to accept more. If what I am thinking is true, what's the best way to handle this. I know we can maintain a in memory queue, but that's problematic as the scale is too big.